Shock malfunctioning after bottom-out
I have another question about suspension (I mean, it is complicated!,) and this time it’s my shock, not related to the other question I asked, about my child’s fork (which I got very good answers for!)
Ahh, if only I was a suspension mechanic… my days would be so much more painless.
I have a Fox Float DPS Performance, (custom tuned for Giant,) that I run at about 230 Psi. The problem is, whenever I bottom out, which isn’t really often, but often enough, it kinda gets insanely plush, like there isn’t any air at all, and then slowly fixes itself after about 5-10 minutes, and is completely fine until I bottom out again.
I have tried putting more and less pressure in, as well as playing around with the rebound, but it still happens anyway.
There really isn’t anything online about this, and seeing as I got great answers last time, I thought I’d see if you peeps had any ideas?
If not, I’m taking it to a proper tuner.
Thanks very much.

I presume you are not needing to add air at all.
It could be the negative chamber getting pressurized by air leaking from positive chamber into negative. Over the next few (hundred) bumps, this pressure bleeds back into the positive chamber and equalizes, returning the shock to normal performance.
Normally, you pump up a shock, you pressurize the positive chamber.  At about 25% of stroke, there is a charge port that opens, bleeding air into the negative chamber. A few bounces are needed to fully equalize this pressure. (When you pump up the shock, you need to bounce it a dozen times before checking sag because of this).
If your shock was leaking air into the negative pressure at bottom of stoke (when the positive pressure is much higher than normal), you would have a much lower positive chamber pressure and much higher negative - it would feel soft - plush.
It is possible that the shock is leaking into the negative chamber before bottoming out, resulting in the ride becoming plush causing the bottom out. Every bump air bleed back though the charge port, equalizing pressure difference. A leak might not be detected if you are cycling the top 50% of the stoke.
After a bottom out when it is feeling plush, get off the bike and check the sag with no weight on the bike. With too much negative pressure, your shock will be partly compressed. Bounce it a few times and see if it returns to normal.
When was the shock last serviced?

Thanks very much- turns out completely deflating it, waiting a few days- and it was good to go!
